# gradient descent function on python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

```
def gradientDescent(X,y,theta,alpha,num_iters):
    print(X.shape,y.shape,theta.shape)
    m = len(y)
    for iter in range(num_iters):
        hypothesis = np.dot(X,theta)
        loss = hypothesis - y
        print("loss {}".format(loss[0]))
        gradient = np.dot(X.transpose(),loss)/m
        theta = theta - alpha*gradient
    return(theta)
```

I have printed shape of X,y,theta and loss for clarification, alpha input = 0.01, num_iters input = 150. The result is diverging after step 6 as follows:

````
(97, 2) (97, 1) (2, 1)
loss [-17.592]
loss [-13.5419506]
loss [-12.82427147]
loss [-12.69896095]
loss [-12.67894766]
loss [-12.67764826]
loss [-12.67967143]
loss [-12.68228117]
loss [-12.68499113]
loss [-12.68771485]
loss [-12.69043697]
loss [-12.69315478]
...
loss [-13.01638377]
loss [-13.01851416]
loss [-13.0206407]
loss [-13.02276341]
loss [-13.0248823]

theta = [[-0.86287834]
 [ 0.88834569]]```
theta should have been  [[-3.6303]
  [1.1664]])
````

Comment: Tweak your learning rate. Or perhaps your model isn't able to learn with the amount of data you've provided. Perhaps it's not possible for your model to ever learn with any amount of data. Anything is plausible.

Comment: I am trying to translate Andrew Ng's matlab machine learning exercise 1 into python. The same data is working fine on matlab.